# Why is the parent pid of a Python process sometimes 0 in Docker containers with docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pid, multiple-processes

When running a python shell directly from a `docker-compose run`, the parent PID shows up as 0, which feels very wrong. I've put together a very simple, reproducible case below:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7-buster
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  thing:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

When I run a python shell from within this, its ppid is 0; likewise to any python code running this way (if running tests with `pytest` for example):

```
$ docker-compose run thing python
>>> import os
>>> os.getpid()
1
>>> os.getppid()
0
```

When I run a python shell from within a bash shell, I see a more sane value...

```
$ docker-compose run thing bash
root@<id> # python
>>> import os
>>> os.getpid()
6
>>> os.getppid()
1
```

When I run the python shell straight on my host machine, I also see more sane PID values...

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.getpid()
25552
>>> os.getppid()
1133
```

I'm sure this is some strange behavior on how `docker` treats processes in a running container, but it doesn't seem to me like a PID should ever be 0. Is this expected behavior, and if so is there a workaround for Python code running this way that relies on a parent PID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is neither strange nor wrong -- the parent PID is 0 because **there is no parent process** in a Docker container.

When running something like `docker-compose run thing python`, the **first process ever** started in that container (or more precisely, in that [PID namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html)) will be the `python` process itself. Therefore, it will get PID 1 and it will not have a parent process.

Note: The exact same thing also happens on regular (non-containerized) Linux systems; the process with PID 1 is also the first process (started by the kernel after booting, in that case) and is usually an init system like [systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd). The init system then handles the user-space part of booting your Linux system (like setting up your network, mounting file systems and starting system services) -- in a Docker container, there's typically no need for any of this, which also eliminates the need for any init system. However, there are init systems like [dumb-init](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/01/dumb-init-an-init-for-docker.html) which are specifically made for running in containers.

When running a shell in a container, and starting Python from that shell, the shell will be PID 1. In that case, running `os.getppid()` from your Python script should return `1`.

> Is this expected behavior, and if so is there a workaround for Python code running this way that relies on a parent PID?

As mentioned, you *could* start your Python environment from a shell (or any other process, for that matter) that would then get PID 1 instead of python. You could also use an init system designed for containers like `dumb-init`.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behavior. The main process inside a container is PID 1 and has no parent. This is part of the isolation of a container--processes appear to be the only process in the entire system.

> When I run a python shell from within a bash shell, I see a more sane value...

In that scenario, the root process is bash and it has a python child process.

Comment: Now, it's worth mentioning in-passing that, if your programs need to use child processes and are not well-behaved, the fact that your program is "pid=1" might cause problems with "zombie processes" within the container.